# Days' is a 'Enum type' but is used like a 'variable

Tags: c#-4.0

I declared Days as Enum, during the code it's treated as normal integer variable, can anybody explains me why like this ?

```
     enum Days { Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri };




    private void set_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (Days)
        {
            case   Days.Fri:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Days` is indeed a type (an `enum`, to be precise), not a variable set to something like `Days.Sat` or `Days.Sun`. Repeating the error message won't make that fact go away.

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to achieve? An error message with a question mark stuck on doesn't constitute a question. Also, I can't believe that "Stack Overflow" was available as a user name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use

```
switch (Days) // <- there must be a variable here
```

but you should have something like this:

```
Days d;
switch (d)
{
    case Days.Fri: break;
}
```

Comment: +1 - for answering a non-question correctly